# "standard limit arguments" involved in showing that roughly every DM stack is locally a quotient stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, stacks, algebraic-stacks

I am trying to understand proposition 3.6 of this paper (perhaps I am in over my head):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703310.pdf

If we denote the stack $\mathcal{M}$ and its coarse moduli space as $M$ then in the first couple of lines of the proof it is written that:

"By standard limit arguments we may assume that $M$ is the spectrum of a local henselian ring $R$ with residue field $k$".

My question is: I have seen what is more or less this same line written in many proofs of different flavors of the above proposition. What are these standard limit arguments and **where** can I find references for them?

Comment: When I write "standard limit arguments" in my own papers, I usually mean: EGA IV_3, Section 8, Sections 11.2 -- 11.3, EGA IV_4, Section 17.7, and maybe Section 19.8.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I just briefly skimmed these sections and they look useful :).